# Cannot install Windows 10 Update kb4093112

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

I cannot seem to install kb4093112, no matter what I do. I even uninstalled it, downloaded it from [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4093112), successfully installed it, yet it always shows me this: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this update. Many people have serious problems after installing this update. My mom couldn't install it either, so for the time being, I disabled Windows updates alltogether. Will enable it in 2 weeks when Microsoft hopefully pulled the update and replaced it with a better one.

Comment: Have you performed a restart per the warning indicating?

Comment: ...yes, I have...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If I understood it correctly, the issue is that KB4093112 (updates for Windows 10 1709) is actually installed, but Windows Update mistakenly thinks that it is not, and keeps asking for you to restart the computer to install it.

For me, the solution was to clean up Windows Update's installation history using this tool: http://www.yourwindowsguide.com/2015/12/windows-update-complete-reset-in.html

Afterwards my "installed update history" was empty. When I selected to look for new updates, Windows Update started installing Windows 10 version 1803, which is what I wanted.